# Why am I getting 'HTTP Version Not Supported' reply when I try to connect to a URL?

Tags: java, url, tomcat, httpresponse, httpurlconnection

The following snippet tries to connect to a url. The url also sends a parameter named `FileNames`. But when I run this snippet, I always get a `HTTP Version Not Supported` reply. What could be the reason for it ?

```java
try {
  URL url = new URL(AddressInformation.clientAddressToSendFileNames + URLEncoder.encode(list.toString(), "UTF-8")); // STATEMENT-1
  HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

  if(connection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
    // File names sent to the client that requested it
    System.out.println("File names sent");
  } else {
     // Error : While trying to send the file names
     System.out.println("Unable to send file names");
     System.out.println("RESPONSE CODE ------->>>>" + connection.getResponseMessage());
   }
} catch(Exception exc) {
   exc.printStackTrace();
  }
```

In the STATEMENT-1, `AddressInformation.clientAddressToSendFileNames` corresponds to

`http://localhost:8084/D Nappster/ReceiveFileNames?FileNames=`.

I am running Tomcat 7.

Comment: What is the full response sent by the other end?

Comment: @fge I didn't understand you

Comment: URL could be the problem.Try encoding all.You notice the space between `D` and `Nappster` in the URL

Comment: Try encoding the space to `%20`

Comment: try `http://localhost:8084/D%20Nappster/ReceiveFileNames?FileNames=`

Comment: @SuhailGupta I'd never have figured out that a URL could be built with an invalid URI to begin with... `new URI("http://a b")` throws a URISyntaxException, whereas `new URL("http://a b")` succeeds :/

Comment: @JanDvorak returns me a `Not Found` message

Comment: @saplingPro is your URL rewriting set-up correctly?

Comment: @JanDvorak URL rewriting? didn't get you

Comment: @saplingPro how did you get the idea that this would be a valid URL? I can see no file extension, files without extensions are extremely rare, and the only rewriting a web server does by default is add `index.something` to the URL if it points to a directory.

Comment: @JanDvorak I am requesting to a servlet.

Comment: @saplingPro then - is your URL binding  set-up correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears your URL is invalid (it contains a space in it), but the URL constructor does not detect that.

You can, instead, use the constructor for `URI` which will correctly encode things for you without you having to worry and then turn it into a URL:

```
URI uri = new URI("http", null, "thehost", theport, "thepath", "thequery", null);
URL url = uri.toURL();
```

Of course, that would require changing your `AddressInformation`.

See the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) for more details.

Comment: Is this URI correct : `URI uri = new URI("http",null,"localhost",8084,AddressInformation.clientAddressToSendFileNames,"FileNames="+list.toString(),null)` ?

Comment: where _FileNames=foo_ is a query string

Comment: and the string `AddressInformation.clientAddressToSendFileNames‌​` corresponds to **D Nappster/ReceiveFileNames**

Comment: If your `list` is actually a `List`, this will not do it since `.toString()` will not output the format expected in a query string. You need to have a utility function which builds the correct query string for you (with no need to escape anything since, again, `URI` does that for you. Also, you need to prepend a `/` before `AddressInformation.clientAddressToSendFileNames`.

Comment: but I am doing _list.toString()_ and then sending the query parameter

Comment: Yes, and this will yield `[entry1, entry2]` -- I doubt the other end expects brackets or spaces between entries.

Comment: Then it means your URL is probably wrong. Are you sure about the path, host, port etc?

Comment: yeah. [This is the code after editing](http://i46.tinypic.com/2jdhq9k.jpg) and this is the constant I am using [AddressInformation.clientAddressToSendFileNames‌​](http://i49.tinypic.com/vdlnck.jpg)

Comment: At this point, I cannot tell you anything but go and see the logs of whatever listens on port 8084 on localhost...

Comment: @saplingPro Everything you presented in the snapshot seems to be correct except the space between `D` and `Nappster` ! I noticed in the above comments that even `D%20Nappster` returns you _Not Found_ code. And the automatic encoding as suggested by this answer will put `%20` between `D` and `Nappster`. Run this application in your browser. How does the browser display the URL ? And try that URL

Answer (score 1):

Well, in my case I solved this problem doing a replace in my url before the httpConnection.getResponseCode() statement: replacing spaces by %20.

Ex:

```html
String url = "http://localhost:8080/Service/methodName?imagem=MY IMAGE NAME";
url = url.replace(" ", "%20");
```

After replacing, the url will look like:

```html
http://localhost:8080/Service/methodName?imagem=MY%20IMAGE%20NAME
```

In order to test it, try to put the url directly into the browser.